# How to stick pop up to top in CSS

Tags: html, css, popup

I am trying to stick my pop up to top and make it a bit smaller to fit the screen.
Here is my landing page URL - yogavoga.com/2weekdiet

Any help will be appreciated.

```
.modal-content {
  margin: 5px auto;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border: 1px solid #888;border-width:3px;
  width: 90%;
  }
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Hi Lidor Amrai. Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: No... only basic css & html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solves your question in full, because your sample code is a bit short and it doesn't show the element itself. I tried visiting your website, but can't find the element. So it is very difficult for us to say what you actually want.

**margin** is the space around your div element, in this case your modal. With your code you say your browser to put your element at the top, (0 margin at the top), and do the rest automatically. It does that and will center your element based on the width of your element.

You can scale your element with **width**. Make it smaller by reducing the percentage.

```
.modal-content {
    margin: 0 auto; // 0 from top, left, bottom and right auto.
    background-color: #fefefe;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    border-width: 3px;
    width: 60%; // Width of your element.
}
```

TIP: remove the margin and padding presets from your body to have your element at the absolute browser border.